# Can the open unit disk be expressed as the union of a countable collection of closed squares?

Tags: real-analysis

My question is simple, but I believe it is challenging think of an example. 
Forget the fact that I couldn't think about an example, I couldn't understand the solution to this.

Need some explanation on it.

Answer :

The closed this $D_n$ of radius $1-\frac{1}{n}$ can be covered by a finite number of squares contained in $D$ and union of all $D_n$ would give us $D$

Q1) How come union of all $D_n$ give us $D$

Q2) Aren't we trying to express the unit circle, instead of covering it?

Comment: I think you want "open unit disc" not the unit circle.

Comment: yes sorry about that :)

Comment: Any solution, if exists, should cover the edge of unit disc using the corners of squares.

Comment: The unit disc can (in some sense) be "approximated" as closely as desired with a finite number of triangles forming a regular polygon with increasing number of sides. What is the distinguishing difference (or point that you want to make) about squares?

Comment: Ok, it is much different in case of open disk. For close disk it is clearly impossible.

Comment: What does it mean to "express" a disk with a collection of squares?

Comment: Do you mean the unit disk, so that the circle is filled in?  And do you mean squares with interior as well?

Comment: Is it a lot to ask that you stop tagging every question involving sets as [set-theory]?

Comment: @bof means that union of those closed squares equals to the disk itself

Comment: @JairTaylor yes i mean the unit disk so that the circle is filled in :) squares are defined to have interiors so yeah.

Comment: @AsafKaragila https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory

Comment: @Xenidia OK. The word "union" was missing.

Comment: Concerning the [tag:set-theory] tag, our [tag wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/set-theory/info) is relevant for whether it's appropriate.

Comment: @DanielFischer define "advanced undergraduate" for $\forall Users$

Comment: Take the union of all squares $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ where $a,b,c,d$ are rational and $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ is contained in the disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open unit disk is  $B_E(0,1)$, a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, where $E$ is the Euclidean metric. We are looking to prove or disprove, that $B_E(0,1)$ can be described with countable unions of $\bar B_M(x_i,r)$, where $M$ is the Manhattan metric, and that the $\bar B$ denotes closed ball. Immediately notice that if the unit disk was closed, there would exist an uncountable union of closed squares: let $T_\theta$ be a transformation that rotates the cordinate system (for example a rotation matrix), and then $M_\theta = M(T_\theta(x),T_\theta(y))$ is a well defined metric. It follows that $$\bar B_E(0,1) = \bigcup_{\theta \in \Theta} \bar B_{M_\theta}(0,1)$$ The following is also true for open unit disk and open squares.

Now for the proof itself: say there does exist $B_E(0,1) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \bar S_n$, where $\bar S_n$ is an arbitrary, closed square. Now, $B$ is open and is a union of sets. Therefore the members in the union need to be open - with respect to $E$ - as well. $\bar S_n$ is homeomorphic to $[a,b] \times [c,d]$. Set $U$ is open if for any $x \in U$, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that, any point $y \in \mathbb R^2$ satisfying $E(x,y)<\epsilon$ means that $y \in U$. Equivalently for every point in $U$, $U$ contains that point's neighbourhood. Take any corner point of $\bar S_n$, in this case $a$: $E(a,y) < 2$ implies we can take $y = a-1$, but $y$ is not in $\bar S_n$, so $\bar S_n$ is not open, and there does not exist a countable collection of closed squares that express the open unit disk. Even more strongly, there does not exists an uncountable collection, as our proof did not rely on the index family $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: If a union of sets is open, it does not follow that all the sets in the union are open. A trivial counterexample is $B=\bigcup_{x\in B} \{x\}$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I wrote this answer in a bit of a hurry. However, I believe that in this case it follows quite strongly that taking any arbitrary union of arbitrary closed squares, that union does have a boundary and from that it follows that $B_E(0,1) \bigcap \partial B_E(0,1) = \emptyset$, but the union $U$ does contain it's boundary and therefore the two sets can not be equal. I will leave my answer unedited, as it is already accepted, and future readers most likely will see my "footnote".

Comment: The union does not necessarily contain its boundary. This would be equivalent to say that the union is closed, but it could be not the case: for instance $(-1,1)=\bigcup_n [-1+\frac1n,1-\frac1n]$. In fact the open disk *can* be written as a countable union of closed squares. A different problem would be to write it as a *disjoint* union.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the set of closed squares of non-zero width,   that are subsets of $D.$ Every $p\in D$ lies at the center of (many) members of $S.$ So the set $T=\{$Int$(s):s\in \}$  of interiors of members of $S,$ is an open cover of $D.$

Now $D$ is a separable metric space so it is a Lindelof space. So there exists a countable $T^*\subset T$ such that $\cup T^*=D.$ Then $S^*=\{\bar t: t\in T^*\}$ is a countable subset of $S,$ and $\cup S^*=D.$